# Parse.com - Getting 400 Bad Request, Using Inner Queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am performing multi-level inner queries but it gives me a 400 Bad Request for the line with the find() function, what have I done wrong?

```
    var EducationVenue = Parse.Object.extend("EducationVenue");
    var EducationVenueRoom = Parse.Object.extend("EducationVenueRoom");
    var EducationLessonSet = Parse.Object.extend("EducationLessonSet");
    var EducationLesson = Parse.Object.extend("EducationLesson");

    var eduLessonSetQuery = new Parse.Query(EducationLessonSet);
    eduLessonSetQuery.matchesQuery("educationListingId", eduListingQuery);

    var eduLessonQuery = new Parse.Query(EducationLesson);
    eduLessonQuery.matchesQuery("educationLessonSetId", eduLessonSetQuery);
    eduLessonQuery.include('educationVenueRoomId.educationVenueId');

    $scope.coursesAtLocations = [];
    eduLessonQuery.find({
      success: function(coursesAtLocations) {
        for (var i = 0; i < coursesAtLocations.length; i++) {
            $scope.coursesAtLocations.push(coursesAtLocations[i]);
            console.log('c at loc' + coursesAtLocations[i]);
        }

      }
    });
```

The reason for this is "query has too many nested queries", what is the more convenient workaround for this?

Comment: $scope.coursesAtLocations.push(coursesAtLocations[i]); this is generating the error?

Comment: I just checked the reason is "query has too many nested queries"... would like to learn about some workarounds that is convenient...